# How to create a dataframe with 2 rows from a one row dataframe based on the dates

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe with one row and 2 date fields of createddate and enddate

How do i get a new dataframe with 2 rows based on those two date fields

I already have a dataframe which looks like

```
+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|      organizationid| id                 |        createddate|              trialenddate|
+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|abcdsdfdlsjdlfkdjfld|abcdsdfdlsjdlfkdjfld|      2017-09-15 13:58:11|     2017-11-30 00:00:00
+--------------------+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

I want the output dataframe to consists of

```
organizationid            startdate      enddate
abcdsdfdlsjdlfkdjfld      2017-09-15     null
abcdsdfdlsjdlfkdjfld      2017-12-01     null
```

Basically my 1st row should come from the createddate column and the 2nd row should come from the next date of the end date. I want to populate the enddate column as well even though it has null values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

The first line makes an array column `startdate` out of `createddate` and `enddate`. The second line explodes the `startdate` list into multiple rows.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn("startdate", F.array(F.col("createddate"), F.col("trialenddate")))
df = df.withColumn("startdate", F.explode(F.col("startdate"))).drop("createddate", "enddate")
```

Comment: TypeError: _() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @Austin Show more of your code, this should not be happening, I removed the `drop()` call, now try and tell me

Comment: The first line itself is giving me the error. 
df = df.withColumn("startdate", F.array(F.col("createddate", "trialenddate")))

Comment: @Austin Sorry, I fixed it. `TypoError` :P

Comment: thank you that worked. But what if i want to populate startdate and enddate both columns?

Comment: Create `end_date` array also like we did for `start_date`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201043/discussion-between-austin-and-pissall).